# Can I encrypt a single folder in Windows Server 2008 R2 with BitLocker?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, encryption, disk-encryption

Using Windows Server 2008 R2, is there a way to encrypt a folder, not the whole disk using Bitlocker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not with BitLocker. BitLocker does full disk encryption. You can use the native file encryption tool that been around for several versions of Windows Server. See *[Enabling File Encryption](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd163562.aspx)* (MSDN).

Comment: thank you Brian. can this encryption be broken if a hacker has physical access to the box (colocated server)?

Comment: I'm not a security expert, but ALL encryption can be broken, some is just harder than others.  Its a matter of mitigating risks.  I believe they can unencrypt if they log in as administrator, with the password (not if they boot into a rescue disk and wipe the password, its protected from that). Pick a very, very good admin password. Does your CoLo allow people to access your physical server? Our has a rack that only us and the colo company has a key to open.

Comment: the problem is that the colo people might want to steal because the colo company has same interst as I do. sounds stupid but in some business areas this is easily the case. it seems the only hope is that the income will be relatively small so they wont do this.